# ASP.NET SPA transpiling TypeScript into JavaScript files

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, typescript, vue.js, single-page-application

I am currently creating a project with ASP.NET spa and Vue.js. I statically serve the dist folder from the Vue.js clientapp, which is the result of the compilation of the clientapp /src (where all .Vue files and .ts files are).
I am currently using the following code as setup for the startup.cs:

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public static void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllers();
        services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration => configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/dist");
        services.AddMvc();

        // Add Singletons for the providers
        services.AddSingleton<IActionDescriptorChangeProvider>(ControllerChangeProvider.Instance);
        services.AddSingleton(ControllerChangeProvider.Instance);

    }

    public static void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseSpaStaticFiles();
        app.UseAuthorization();
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => endpoints.MapControllers());
        app.UseSpa(spa => { });
    }
}
```

.csproj:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <RootNamespace>MyApplication</RootNamespace>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis" Version="3.5.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.FxCopAnalyzers" Version="3.0.0">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CSharp" Version="4.7.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Text.Json" Version="4.7.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="VueCliMiddleware" Version="3.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Now, I have some TypeScript files in my /src (such as a /router/index.ts) and they work fine when running a static server (with npm for example) on the dist folder. However, for some reason when I run the ASP.NET server with ISS it transpiles the .ts files into .js files in the /src folder. This does not influence anything, however it is unnecessary code.

I have run my application with a breakpoint at the very beginning of the application (the main method) and the transpiling happens before the main method. So I assume it is a configuration.

So my question is, **is there an option to turn the transpilation of the .ts files off in asp.net?**

Any feedback is welcome and I will provide with any necessary info when needed. :)

Comment: You do not want Asp.Net Cores build pipeline to automatically build the client app for you?

Comment: Yes, I build my clientapp in a different way (so not with ASP.NET)

Comment: Did you use a specific dotnet template from `dotnet new` or inside visual studio?

Comment: I used the `Vue JS Template AspNet Core 3.1 Web API` template

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more debugging, it turned out that Visual Studio automatically transpiles TypeScript files on default when building. To turn this off I used:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <RootNamespace>Application</RootNamespace>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>

    <!-- Makes the TypeScript compilation task a no-op -->
    <TypeScriptCompileBlocked>true</TypeScriptCompileBlocked>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Answer (score 0):

For some reason I don't have the Vue template, so I took the React template - the steps should be the same.

The build process for asp.net core is wired together inside your `.csproj` file. Remove the following sections from it, to disable to automatic build of your spa, when you build your application.

```
  <Target Name="DebugEnsureNodeEnv" BeforeTargets="Build" Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Debug' And !Exists('$(SpaRoot)node_modules') ">
    <!-- Ensure Node.js is installed -->
    <Exec Command="node --version" ContinueOnError="true">
      <Output TaskParameter="ExitCode" PropertyName="ErrorCode" />
    </Exec>
    <Error Condition="'$(ErrorCode)' != '0'" Text="Node.js is required to build and run this project. To continue, please install Node.js from https://nodejs.org/, and then restart your command prompt or IDE." />
    <Message Importance="high" Text="Restoring dependencies using 'npm'. This may take several minutes..." />
    <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm install" />
  </Target>

  <Target Name="PublishRunWebpack" AfterTargets="ComputeFilesToPublish">
    <!-- As part of publishing, ensure the JS resources are freshly built in production mode -->
    <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm install" />
    <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm run build" />

    <!-- Include the newly-built files in the publish output -->
    <ItemGroup>
      <DistFiles Include="$(SpaRoot)build\**" />
      <ResolvedFileToPublish Include="@(DistFiles->'%(FullPath)')" Exclude="@(ResolvedFileToPublish)">
        <RelativePath>%(DistFiles.Identity)</RelativePath>
        <CopyToPublishDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToPublishDirectory>
        <ExcludeFromSingleFile>true</ExcludeFromSingleFile>
      </ResolvedFileToPublish>
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>
```

The first section ensures NodeJs is actually installed, while the second calls the npm scripts.

Comment: I had a look at my csproj file, but it does not contain anything like this, I have updated my post with my csproj file.